# The requested resource could not be found in Omnipay/Pin Payments

Tags: payment, omnipay

I'm trying to get Omnipay to work with Pin Payments.

This is what I have so far:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Omnipay\Common\GatewayFactory;

$gateway = GatewayFactory::create('Pin');
$gateway->setSecretKey('KEY');
$gateway->setTestMode(true);
$response=$gateway->purchase(array(
  'amount'      => 1.00,
  'description' => 'test charge',
  'email'       => 'danielbk08@gmail.com',
  'currency'    => 'USD',
  'ip_address'  => '1.53.227.0',
   'card'        => array(
    'number'           => '4111111111111111',
    'expiry_month'     => '06',
    'expiry_year'      => '2016',
    'cvc'              => '333',
    'name'             => 'le minh luan',
    'address_line1'    => '184A Nguyen Thanh Vinh St Dist 12',
    'address_city'     => 'Ho Chi Minh City',
    'address_postcode' => '70000',
    'address_state'    => 'Ho Chi Minh City',
    'address_country'  => 'Vietnam'
  )
))->send();

if ($response->isSuccessful()) {
    // payment was successful: update database
    print_r($response);
} elseif ($response->isRedirect()) {
    // redirect to offsite payment gateway
    $response->redirect();
} else {
    // payment failed: display message to customer
    echo $response->getMessage();
}
?>
```

And I got the error "The requested resource could not be found."
Any help appreciated :)

Comment: Not sure whether this is related or not, but you only need to pass either `token` or `card`, but not both (use `token` if you are using Pin's javascript API to submit the card details directly to their server).

Comment: Hi Adrian Macneil.
Actually I removed token and I still got that issue. Seem have some wrongs here

Comment: What happens if you `print_r($response->getData())`?

Comment: Array ( [error] => not_found [error_description] => The requested resource could not be found. )

Comment: Ok I think you better contact Pin support about that one. It sounds like something might be wrong with their test environment.

Comment: Okei, Thanks Adrian Macneil